# Effects of exposure to Solar/Lunar eclipse on Human body

Tags: physical-health

How does Solar/Lunar eclipse affect human body when one is directly exposed to it (by getting outdoors while an eclipse is in progress)? E.g. it is generally not advised to look towards a Solar eclipse in progress with naked eyes.

On a related note, what are the day to day activities one should refrain from doing during eclipse while being either indoor or outdoor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASA has [this](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/do-lunar-and-solar-eclipses-have-any-noticeable-effect-humans) to say about the effects of eclipses on humans:

> There is no evidence that eclipses have any physical effect on humans. However, eclipses have always been capable of producing profound psychological effects. For millennia, solar eclipses have been interpreted as portents of doom by virtually every known civilization. These have stimulated responses that run the gamut from human sacrifices to feelings of awe and bewilderment. Although there are no direct physical effects involving known forces, the consequences of the induced human psychological states have indeed led to physical effects.

In other words, any effects are psychosomatic, they exist only because one believes they exist. There cannot be any possible physical effect caused by eclipses, both lunar or solar, as there are absolutely no physical effects (gravitational, magnetic, or otherwise) caused by the particular alignment that produces eclipses. (Tidal effects to not apply to objects as small as a human body, because the difference in gravity produced by the earth, sun, or moon between the top of your body and the bottom is nil.)
It is commonly believed that one should not look at the sun during a solar eclipse, and this is true if the eclipse is partial, [annular](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/k-4/stories/annular-eclipse), and before and after a total eclipse. NASA's [2017 Eclipse site](https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/eclipse-misconceptions) says this about viewing the total eclipse:

> During a total solar eclipse when the disk of the moon fully covers the sun, the brilliant corona emits only electromagnetic radiation, though sometimes with a greenish hue. Scientists have studied this radiation for centuries. Being a million times fainter than the light from the sun itself, there is nothing in the coronal light that could cross 150 million kilometers of space, penetrate our dense atmosphere, and cause blindness. However, if you watched the sun before totality, you will catch a glimpse of the brilliant solar surface and this can cause retinal damage, though the typical human instinctual response is to quickly look away before any severe damage has actually occurred.

The aforementioned site also covers some of the other myths about solar eclipses such as pregnancies, food poisoning, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While the answer is quite helpful, I am also curious to learn about common conceptions like it is not advised to look with naked eyes towards a solar eclipse etc.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema There are some questions on other SE sites that touch on this topic: [Are dangerous rays emitted during Solar Eclipse?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11087), [Why aren't 100% UV blocked sunglasses safe to view an eclipse with?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352914), [Is it safe to watch solar eclipse's reflection in water?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13948), [How to test direct sun viewing glasses?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21822), [How will the eclipse affect my pet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18038)

Comment: @NimeshNeema, sorry. It was not immediately obvious from your question that you were asking about looking directly at a solar eclipse, though I probably should have considered that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BillDOe. Including directing looking towards Solar/Lunar eclipse, I intend to learn about the all-round effect of getting exposed to Solar/Lunar eclipse. Please take the liberty to edit the question if that's not obvious.